# Most efficient way to get all ID's from a collection

Tags: magento-1, collection

In the past to get all ID's of a product collection, I have always used `getAllIds` on the collection, believing this was a method that prevented the full collection load with data etc.

But, I actually looked at the method today and it loads the collection and iterates over each item to get the ID array.

```
public function getAllIds()
{
    $ids = array();
    foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
        $ids[] = $this->_getItemId($item);
    }
    return $ids;
}
```

My question is, what is the most efficient method to retrieve only the ID field from a collection?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Actually `getAllIds` is the best way of doing it. For example in the product collection resource model the method looks like this:

```
public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
{
    $idsSelect = $this->_getClearSelect();
    $idsSelect->columns('e.' . $this->getEntity()->getIdFieldName());
    $idsSelect->limit($limit, $offset);
    $idsSelect->resetJoinLeft();

    return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($idsSelect, $this->_bindParams);
}
```

So everything is retrieved from a single select and no iteration is required.
Also in the abstract resource model it looks like this:

```
public function getAllIds()
{
    $idsSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $idsSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $idsSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $idsSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $idsSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

    $idsSelect->columns($this->getResource()->getIdFieldName(), 'main_table');
    return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($idsSelect);
}
```

So everything that extends `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` should use this unless specified otherwise.

The method you looked at comes from the base class `Varien_Data_Collection` but it is overwritten in its children.

Answer (score 7):

In this case you can use the collection object

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id');

[...] 
do your loop
[...]
```

`addAttributeToSelect` for `entity_id` is not really required but for demonstrating purposes I put it in, add the fields you need and you're done!

More on collections you'll find [on this Wikipage](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)

Answer (score 2):

More Optimized

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
$collection->getSelect()->columns('entity_id');
$collection1Ids[] = $collection->getAllIds();
```

Comment: This is also done by default ... see `$this->_getClearSelect()`.